# Why can't I move WhatsApp to the SD card on my HTC One M8?

Tags: sd-card, whatsapp-messenger, htc-one

I picked up a new SD card for my HTC One M8 and am trying to move my apps from my phone to the card. I can move almost every app but for WhatsApp, the *Move* button is greyed out:

[image: cannot move WhatsApp]

Does anyone know why? The SD card isn't full or even nearly full.

Comment: Did you try any 3rd party apps? Is the issue specific to Whatsapp or other apps? Also, rooting would give this functionality am sure.

Comment: WhatsApp must not support it: [Unable to move few Apps to SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27816/unable-to-move-few-apps-to-sd-card)

Comment: Have you checked whether your Internal SD Card space is full?
In Android, the internal memory is partitioned into Internal Storage, where the Android system is, and Internal SD Card, where the apps go. When you are moving them using the normal method, then the apps merely get shifted from one partition to the other. They actually don't go to your SD Card, unless your phone is rooted, and your Ext. SD Card is partitioned to two primary partitions, and you are moving these apps using Link2SD or any similar application. Again, is your phone rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [WhatsApp FAQ for Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/21068307),

> ## How do I move WhatsApp to the microSD card?
>
> Moving WhatsApp to your memory card (microSD card) is not possible at this time.
>
> We are working on improving our application size and memory utilization. There are technical hurdles that do not allow us to move our application to the microSD card. In the meantime, we recommend that you help make room for WhatsApp by moving as many other applications and media files as you can, to your microSD card.

They didn't explain any technical reason why it's not possible, but apps are configurable to not be movable to SD card, as explained on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106125/44325).

Comment: When I transfer WhatsApp photos and videos to my SD card, they get corrupted and greyed out after sometime. Why do you think this happens?