# Cannot move app to sd-card?

Tags: applications, sd-card, app2sd

My sdcard has plenty free space but I cannot move any apps. On my sdcard there's the old  Android/data path with many older apps. Why cannot it be possible to move apps here? Maybe I can create a symlink?

Comment: I've just added the `app2sd` tag to your question. You might want to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) and [frequent questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app2sd?sort=frequent), as that's asked quite often ([Unable to move few Apps to SD Card](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27816/16575) / [Can I force move to sd card applications that don't want to be moved there?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16987/16575) and more).

Comment: Thank you but I read the wiki. My apps is moveable in Android system setting (and also app2sd) but when I push the button it gives me an error unable to move.

Comment: Well, it looks like you should [edit] your question and add all the details it's missing; our crystal balls are all out for maintenance currently ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. I wrote I have old path Android/data in my sdcard with many old apps.

Comment: Maybe you describe step-by-step what you've tried to achieve your goal, and what happened. Don't forget to include any possible error message. E.g. your comment above introduces a detail missing in the question: you push a button (where?) and it gives an error "unable to move" (move what? which app? Maybe the app doesn't support App2SD?).

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know even android system settings?

Comment: This is not a chatroom here – but we have one of course. Maybe you want to come over there to discuss it?

Comment: @Izzy: I apologize, I should add old to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.  I need to be root to move the apps.

Comment: You may have found that being root allows you to move apps to the SD card, but that is usually no needed. Perhaps in your case (and it may work for others too) it is a workaround.